# PDO Stmt: Is this how it should be done?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First of all I want to say that I'm new to PDO. I did tried it once but since I found the oop solution complicated and even impossible (`SELECT * FROM table_name`) I decided to use PDO.

But I'm not sure if I do it right, so I'd like to take criticism about what I've done. I'm "translating" the mysqli stmt to pdo. Here's an example from one thing I've "translated":

```
// Client IP has been defined previously,
// But for the example:
$ip     = '3ffe:1900:4545:3:200:f8ff:fe21:67cf';
$sql_ip = inet_pton($ip); // IPV6

try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE s_ipv4 = :s_ipv4 OR s_ipv6 = :s_ipv6');
    $stmt->bindParam(':s_ipv4', $sql_ip);
    $stmt->bindParam(':s_ipv6', $sql_ip);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() === 0) {
        // No rows
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    die ($exception->getMessage());
}

unset($stmt);
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: What should be wrong? If it works, you're fine :)

Comment: this question is suitable for the plateform:- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is suitable for :-[Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Technically it's all right, it should be just 3 times shorter and without that awful "die" stuff. For the full review post it on the https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: codereview - Will do. Thank you everybody!